# Adding a new view to constraint leads to a weird crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code looks something like this:

```
UICollectionView *myCollectionView= myCollectionVC.collectionView;

myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:myCollectionView];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[myCollectionView]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myCollectionView)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myCollectionView]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myCollectionView)]];
```

This works fine - I can see the collection view.

But when I try adding another sub view it crashes:

```
UICollectionView *myCollectionView= myCollectionVC.collectionView;
UIView *newView = [UIView new];

newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:myCollectionView];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[myCollectionView]-[newView(>=10)]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myCollectionView,newView)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myCollectionView]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myCollectionView)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[newView]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(newView)]];
```

It crashes with the following error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'negative sizes are not
>   supported in the flow
>   layout'

The new view is just an empty view - but why is it thinking that it is a negative-sized view.

Comment: Try setting frame to newView like this: 
new.frame = CGRectZero

Comment: I think the problem is that there is not enough constraints to decide what the height should be for the new view and the collection view. Because you're just setting an inequality constraint for the height of the new view. Plus you're not setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints for the new view.

Comment: You have a relative size for your new view and so it is pushing the collection view off the screen entirely as the collection view has no content.